# I have installed the "install-dbatools" powershell script, but there is no copy-sqllogin or export-sqllogin function

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dbatools

I have installed the "install-dbatools.ps1" powershell module and it installs successfully, however the functions i am looking for are not there, these functions are "Copy-SQLLogin and "Export-SQLLogin" as per the below

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4654/migrate-sql-server-logins-with-powershell/

I have also run the invoke command below
Invoke-Expression (Invoke-WebRequest  http://git.io/vn1hQ).Content

have these commands been deprecated? as i am trying to migrate SQL Logins, roles, permission etc etc to a different server, or how can i achieve this in the best possible way.

SP_HelpRevLogin only does half of this.
Thanks for any assistance

I have downloaded and installed dbatools as per:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4654/migrate-sql-server-logins-with-powershell/

I have also run the invoke command below as per:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Fully-TransferMigrate-SQL-25a0cf05#content/

Invoke-Expression (Invoke-WebRequest  http://git.io/vn1hQ).Content

Invoke-Expression (Invoke-WebRequest  http://git.io/vn1hQ).Content

i expect the commands Copy-SQLLogin and Export-SQLLogin to be available in order to migrate  SQL Logins, roles, permission etc etc to a different server, or how can i achieve this in the best possible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *-SqlLogin tools got renamed some time ago. Try:

```bsh
Get-Command | ? { $_.Name -like '*-DbaLogin' }

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Copy-DbaLogin                                      1.0.34     dbatools
Function        Export-DbaLogin                                    1.0.34     dbatools
Function        Get-DbaLogin                                       1.0.34     dbatools
Function        New-DbaLogin                                       1.0.34     dbatools
Function        Remove-DbaLogin                                    1.0.34     dbatools
Function        Rename-DbaLogin                                    1.0.34     dbatools
Function        Set-DbaLogin                                       1.0.34     dbatools
```